# How to use the button on a headset?

Tags: microphone, bias, headphones

I want to implement push to talk on my custom PCB.

I apply a 2V DC bias on the microphone line of the jack through a 2.2k resistor. While pressing the button of the headset I see the resistance between MIC and GND fall to 1.3ohms (I guess the exact value will change with different headset.)

My question is:

Can I still use the microphone while the button is pressed?
If I can can you tell me if I can directly send the MIC to my MCU (for detection of the button) and to my [microphone amplifier](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX9814.pdf).

I've read the [Android documentation](https://source.android.com/devices/accessories/headset/jack-headset-spec) but I didn't answer my question.

Comment: Are you using a standard Android headset?

Comment: Yes It's a standard headset by Sony compatible with Android, It only got a button (function A on the drawing in the first answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

*Figure 1. Source: [Android.com](https://source.android.com/devices/accessories/headset/plug-headset-spec)*

> Can I still use the microphone while the button is pressed? If I can can you tell me if I can directly send the MIC to my MCU (for detection of the button) and to my microphone amplifier.

According to Figure 1 pressing Button A will short-circuit the microphone. You will get no audio from the mic while the button is pressed. The MCU can detect the button press by the monitoring V<sub>eq</sub> which will fall to zero.

Comment: I've read the doc it seems that I can't do push-to-talk this way, I want to know if another way exist

Comment: If the button in the headset shorts out the mic signal then you can't.